# Using IPP for Matrix Inversion using OpenCV 3.0

Tags: opencv, intel-ipp

[Here](http://opencv.org/opencv-3-0-alpha.html) discusses OpenCV 3.0 & the now "Transparent API" for using IPP by Intel.

It shows this picture:
[image]

My question is does anyone know if it will affect Matrix Inversion? Will it speed up the Mat::inv method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, IPP is not used for matrix inversion. Look at cv::invert in lapack.cpp.